# What is the Difference Between Dyadic Pigeonhole Principle and the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: definition, pigeonhole-principle

I have recently heard and read the term "dyadic pigeonhole principle" (e.g. [see these posts by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dyadic-pigeonholing/)). However, is dyadic pigeonholing just a special case of "classical" pigeonholing where there are two (hence the word dyadic) holes?

Apologies in advance if this post is an overly trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Tao's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06736.pdf), "dyadic pigeonholing" is a name he (Tao) gave to the following technique:

> ... dyadic decomposition is combined with the pigeonhole principle to
> locate a single “good” scale in which to run additional arguments. We refer to this combination of dyadic decomposition and the pigeonhole principle as dyadic pigeonholing.

(Section 4., p. 5). It does not refer to the pigeonhole principle with two holes; perhaps more like $2^n$ holes.